# free(): Invalid pointer in only one case

Tags: c++

When I run this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *a = NULL;
    char *b = NULL;
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    a = new char[n];
    b = new char[n];
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Freeing a" << endl;

    delete []a;
    cout << "Freeing b" << endl;
    delete []b;

    a = NULL;
    b = NULL;
}
```

For the following input:

```
168
110101001110100001000100000000101001100000111000110000011010110001011101000000011000101111100011010011101000001001001101000100000001111001101011100101101001111001110100
110101001110000001000100000000100001100000110100100100011110100001011101000000011000111101101010010011101110001101001101000100000001011001101011100101101001111001110100
```

I get the following ouput:

```
Freeing a
Freeing b
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I see that the program fails to delete the memory allocated for `b`.

Observations:

It fails only for this case. Seems to run for other inputs with different length than 168.

Edit:

The null character not being accounted could have been an error. But I dont get any error for this input:

```
10
1010101010
1010101010
```

Deleting always fails for the second pointer.

Comment: You  input 168 chars PLUS a null terminator - so your arrays are not big enough. Result - undefined behaviour. If you used std::string instead of arrays, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Shouldnt the same problem occur if n was 167 and the length of strings were also 167. Strings would still be 167 + \0. But I dont get the same run time error.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Your second example _still_ has UB - it just appears to "work". Why the heck can't you create the correct sized arrays? Or use std::string?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I know that using the strings class is the better way to do it. This was only for educational purpose. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) to read *characters* into a dynamic array, use [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to tell `operator>>` how large the array actually is so it won't overflow the array:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>

cin >> setw(n) >> a;
cin >> setw(n) >> b;
```

Otherwise, use [`istream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) or [`istream::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) instead:

```cpp
cin.read(a, n);
cin.read(b, n);
```

```cpp
cin.get(a, n);
cin.get(b, n);
```

Either way, make sure the array is large enough to hold the number of characters you want to read + a null terminator! The reads above all output a null terminator after reading `width-1` number of characters max.

```cpp
cin >> n;
++n; // for null terminator
```